# .post displays variable in URL on submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, http-post, processing

I'm using the `$.post` method to post a value through to a PHP page for processing after using serialize and I replaced the serialize utility with a more specific element:

```
$("button").click(function(event) {
    $.post(
        "php/index.php",
        { seq: $("seq").val(); },
        function(data, status) {
            $('.stage').html(data);
        }
    );
});
```

However the data doesn't get sent and it appears in the URLlike this:

> xxx.co.uk/?seq=123456

Very similar to a `get` method. How can I adjust this to send it to a PHP page with the value from the form element and to receive it as:

```
$_POST['seq'];
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you submitting the form?

Comment: don't you think this should be id `#` or class `.` : $("seq").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $("button").click(function(event) {
  $.post(
    "php/index.php",
    { seq: $("#seq").val() }, // or class $(".seq").val()
    function(data, status) {
        $('.stage').html(data);
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, the button is inside of a form and you do not prevent the default action on the button? That is, the browser submits the form instead of doing your $.post?

If that is the case, simply do `e.preventDefault();` last in your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
       $.post(
      "php/index.php",
       { seq: $("#seq").val() }, 
       function(data, status) {
      $('.stage').html(data);
    }
   );
});
```

Comment: The only useful thing in this answer is the ("#seq") part. Better use $.post like the original poster imo.